# Copying folders using SAS X command: issues with quotations and special characters

Tags: windows, command-line, sas

I am trying to copy a set of folders using [sas x command](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-cmd-x.htm). The folders contain  a mix of files of various types.

Let's assume the following file structure

```
D:\tmp\Src - directory with source folders
D:\tmp\Dest - destination directory
```

within the source directory I am interested in a subset of folders with names `Data*` eg: `Data 1`, `Data 2` etc.

Defining source and destination main directories as macro variables:

```
%let srcLoc=D:\tmp\Src;
%let destLoc=D:\tmp\Dest;
```

we can run

```
x xcopy "&SrcLoc.\Data 1" "&destLoc.\Data 1" /q /i /y;
x xcopy "&SrcLoc.\Data 2" "&destLoc.\Data 2" /q /i /y;
/*etc */
```

And all works fine.

**Intended modification**

As with time, new folders will be added to source directory there is a need to write a universal code that would process all the folders that conform to naming `Data*`.

The following performs the task required task when executed directly within windows command line

```
FOR /F "tokens=*"  %G IN ('dir /B /A:D "D:\tmp\Src\Data*"') DO xcopy "D:\tmp\Src\%G" "D:\tmp\Dest\%G" /q /i /y
```

**Issue:**

When attempting to execute the same from within SAS:

```
%let srcLoc=D:\tmp\Src;
%let destLoc=D:\tmp\Dest;

/* just to test resolving of macro variables */
%put FOR /F "tokens=*"  %G IN ('dir /B /A:D "&srcLoc.\Data*"') DO xcopy "&srcLoc.\%G" "&destLoc.\%G" /q /i /y;

/* the actual x-command */
x FOR /F "tokens=*"  %G IN ('dir /B /A:D "&srcLoc.\Data*"') DO xcopy "&srcLoc.\%G" "&destLoc.\%G" /q /i /y;
```

There are the following issues:

- a warning `WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro G not resolved.` and
- the resolved string is actually `FOR /F "tokens=*"  %G IN ('dir /B /A:D "&srcLoc.\Data*"') DO xcopy "D:\tmp\Src\%G" "D:\tmp\Dest\%G" /q /i /y`

As you can see the `&srcLoc.` did not resolve to a value as it is enclosed with single quotation marks needed to call `('dir /B /A:D "&srcLoc.\Data*"')`

**Question:**

How to ensure that `%G` is not treated as macro and also ensure that `&srcLoc.` resolves to the actual value?

Also is there a better way to accomplish the above task within sas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better method, but for now I suggest you try one of the following:

**Quote each problematic character individually**

```
x FOR /F "tokens=*"  %nrstr(%)G IN (%bquote(')dir /B /A:D "&srcLoc.\Data*"%bquote(')) DO xcopy "&srcLoc.\%nrstr(%)G" "&destLoc.\%nrstr(%)G" /q /i /y;
```

**Quote everything using masking `%` characters within a single `%str`**

```
x %str(FOR /F "tokens=*"  %%G IN (%'dir /B /A:D "&srcLoc.\Data*"%') DO xcopy "&srcLoc.\%%G" "&destLoc.\%%G" /q /i /y);
```